# Unity DI Registered Instances not injected correctly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository, unity-container

I'm having problems with the resolution of instances in unity

I've set up the container like this:

```
var token = new SecurityToken();
token.Token = "Test";
token.Value = "Test";

var passport = new PassportContext();
passport.Permissions = new SecurityPermissions { Add = true, Change = true, Inquiry = true, Delete = true };

_unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
_unityContainer.RegisterInstance<PassportContext>(passport, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_unityContainer.RegisterInstance<SecurityToken>(token, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_unityContainer.RegisterType<IWorksheetRepository, WorksheetRepository>();
```

`PassportContext` and `SecurityToken` are required for the web service calls in the repository to get the data.

I resolve my `WorksheetRepository` like this:

```
UnityContainer.Resolve<IWorksheetRepository>();
```

which instantiates my `WorksheetRepository`:

```
public sealed class WorksheetRepository : IWorksheetRepository
{
    private PassportContext _passportContext;
    private SecurityToken _token;

    public WorksheetRepository(PassportContext passportContext, SecurityToken token)
    {
        _passportContext = passportContext;
        _token = token;
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is, in the `WorksheetRepository` constructor, both `PassportContext` and `SecurityToken` are instantiated, but all properties are at their default values, not the ones I set in my setup.  I set them as singletons, so when I resolve `IWorksheetRepository` shouldn't my singletons have been injected into my `WorksheetRepository` implementation?  Am I missing something with unity here?

A bit of background - I'm trying to follow best practices.  I understand that most of your application should be ignorant of your Unity container, it should resolve dependencies from the root of the application.  That's the pattern I'm trying to follow, though this is a Unit Test.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you describe.  Given the exact code you have here, I am able to resolve the repository with the correct passport context and security token.  Do you have something registering types (maybe by convention?) into the container after your RegisterInstance calls that may be overwriting those registrations?  Do you have multiple unity containers?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example, I used InjectionProperty here to supply the instance.

```
public class SecurityPermissions
{
    public bool Add { get; set; }
    public bool Change { get; set; }
}

public class PassportContext
{
    public SecurityPermissions MyProperty { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void YourUnitTest()
{

using (var c = new UnityContainer())
{
    var sp = new SecurityPermissions() { Add = true, Change = true };

    c.RegisterType(typeof(PassportContext), new InjectionProperty("MyProperty", sp));
    var pc = c.Resolve<PassportContext>();
```